# Why are tags only visible at the main page when we are signed-out?

Tags: support, feature-request

I wasn't paying attention to this till now.

When signed in there are no suggested tags a the top of the page:

[[image]]

When not signed in I get a list of tags to "explore":

[[image]]

Why not having the tags visible forever?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because when you are signed in, the application already knows what tags you are interested in, or assumes you are somewhat familiar with the site.  When you are signed out, it has no idea who you are, so the site designers are suggesting some tags to "Explore".

This is arguably just good website design.  When you are an experienced user, who knows are tags are, why would you want a list of tags taking up a load of space at the top of your page.

Also:

1. I really suggest you describe the problem a little more clearly, I didn't understand what you were asking at first
2. You can size your images to be less dominant in the question - read [this question on it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189635/how-do-i-set-the-size-of-a-picture-in-my-question-post).
3. We have literally no influence over how the website works, as one of the many many sites hosted here.  You would be better off asking this on [Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I didn't see any problems in describing the matter, before my question was edited. **Why not having the tags visible forever?** clears what I'm asking here.